# What is the characteristic property of surjective submersions?

Tags: manifolds

In [Lee's 'Introduction to smooth manifolds'](http://books.google.co.uk/books?id=xygVcKGPsNwC&pg=PA88&lpg=PA88&dq=topological+embedding+closed+map&source=bl&ots=j_LsQYWfWQ&sig=xy3EujcPJmiN8o47tedMglvvRb0&hl=en&sa=X&ei=e6n0ULvJCsmQ0QW8voHwAg&ved=0CEQQ6AEwAw#v=onepage&q=topological%20embedding%20closed%20map&f=false) he states that given smooth manifolds $X,Y$ and a surjective submersion $f:X\to Y$, then $f$ is a smoothly *final* map, that is for any further smooth manifold $Z$, and *any* map $g:Y\to Z$, we have $g$ smooth iff $g\circ f$ is smooth.

He then says that problem 4.7 shows why this property is 'characteristic'. I can't see why the reverse implication should hold.

Unfortunately, google-books doesn't show that page, can some-one enlighten me as to what he means?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The intention of this statement was clarified by the author Jack Lee [on MathOverflow](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/119732/):

> Here's what I had in mind:
>
> **Theorem:** *Suppose $M$ and $N$ are smooth manifolds and $\pi\colon M \to N$ is a surjective smooth submersion. Then the given topology and smooth structure on $N$ are the only ones that satisfy the characteristic property.*
>
> (That's what Problem 4-7 asks you to prove.)

Comment: Thanks. I asked the question in math overflow as I was getting any luck here...

Comment: Sure, there's nothing wrong with that -- although next time it would be nice to provide links both here and on MO. I posted this so that you have an answer to accept and in order to let other people know that the matter was settled elsewhere.

Comment: @MoziburUllah Apparently, [user1421](http://math.stackexchange.com/users/1421/jack-lee) did not notice your question here... Maybe the chance of noticing would be higher if the question was also tagged `differential-geometry` (`manifolds` by itself does not make it clear that the question is about smooth manifolds).

Comment: @5pm: you're probably right.